# Spring-Boot: How do I reference application.properties in an @ImportResource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an applicationContext.xml file in my Spring Boot application. In this file, it has a property placeholder - ${profile.services.url} - that's used to configure the "address" property of a <jaxws:client> bean.

In my Application.java class, I import this file.

```
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have "profile.services.url" defined in application.properties. However, it's not recognized when building the bean in my XML file. I've tried adding the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
```

Any suggestions on how to get @ImportResource to recognize Spring Boot's property support?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've got the following code:

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

import java.util.Collection;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        Collection<Foo> shouldBeConfigured = applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Foo.class).values();
        System.out.println(shouldBeConfigured.toString());
    }
}

@Configuration
@ImportResource("/another.xml")
class XmlImportingConfiguration {
}

class Foo {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

I have a Spring XML configuration file, `another.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="another.properties" />

    <!-- this property value is defined in another.properties, which we install in this XML file
    -->
    <bean class="demo.Foo" >
        <property name="name" value="${name.property}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- this property value is defined in application.properties, which Spring Boot automatically installs for us.
    -->
    <bean class="demo.Foo" >
        <property name="name" value="${some.property}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I have the following `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Finally, I have two `.properties` files, `another.properties`, and `application.properties`:

```
# application.properties 
some.property=Test
```

and..

```
# another.properties 
name.property=Another
```

When I run this, the output is:

> [Foo{name='Another'}, Foo{name='Test'}]

Which would seem to work.

I'm not quite sure I am understanding the error. Can you elaborate, or confirm this seems satisfactory behavior for you, too please?

Comment: Thanks Josh - I was able to use this to prove that the property is getting set (and read) from application.properties. The problem I'm experiencing now is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748499/jaxwsclient-address-property-not-resolving-placeholder#comment32408122_19748499. In other words, the "address" attribute of <jaxws:client> seems to be re-evaluated at runtime and there's no property substitution at that point.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to workaround my issue by configuring my Soap service in JavaConfig instead of XML:

```
@Value("${profile.services.url}")
private String profileServiceUrl;

@Bean
public ProfileSoapService profileSoapService() {
    final JaxWsProxyFactoryBean jaxWsProxyFactoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setServiceClass(ProfileSoapService.class);
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.setAddress(profileServiceUrl);
    jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.getOutInterceptors().add(getSecurityInterceptor());
    return (ProfileSoapService) jaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create();
}


private WSS4JOutInterceptor getSecurityInterceptor() { ... }
```