# Which type of resource file to use to store constants

Tags: java, xml, properties-file, resource-files

I am developing an application that tests web Services, and I use [JUnit parameterized tests](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/). I want to read parameters from a resources file.
I  am wondering which is the best way to store these parameters.

1. In a .properties file ?

   ```
   test1.inputPath= C:\\Path
   test1.expectedOutputPath= C:\\Path
   test2.inputPath= C:\\Path2
   test2.expectedOutputPath= C:\\Path2
   ```
2. In an xml file?

   ```
   <test>
     <inputPath>  C:\Path <\inputPath>
     <expectedOutputPath>  C:\Path <\expectedOutputPath>
   <\test>
   <test>
     <inputPath>  C:\Path2 <\inputPath>
     <expectedOutputPath>  C:\Path2 <\expectedOutputPath>
   <\test>
   ```
3. Other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think first one works quite well

Comment: Do you know another type of resource file that I can use and which is easier to read than a .properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I found for my problem is to use PropertiesConfiguration of [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html). It is very simple to use:

In my .properties file :

```
test1= Path1,Path2
test2= Path3,Path4
```

Then I read the .properties file automatically and I retrieve paths as a String array for each test.

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> readPropertiesFile(){
    ArrayList<Object[]> result= new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    try {
        Configuration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("testPaths.properties");
        Iterator<String> keys=config.getKeys();
        while(keys.hasNext()){
            String[] paths= config.getStringArray(keys.next());
            result.add(paths);          
        }
    } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to make your life more complicated ;) You can easily read property files in this way:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
prop.load(input);
String s = prop.getProperty("test1.inputPath");
```

and import:

```
import java.util.Properties;
```

is it still complicated for you?

Comment: I am writing generic tests, and I want to read all parameters of a test automatically. I found a solution for my problem by using PropertiesConfiguration of Apache Commons Configuration.

Comment: Perfect. Could you post your answer here?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, of course, there are MANY ways of doing it.

First ask yourself: do these properties will change? Are they parameters or are they constants?
For example, the number of the states, what are the chances they will change? In this case you need a constant, not a parameter.

Now, if you are looking for something that can changed at runtime then you should look into properties and resource bundles.

---

If all you need are constants, then you can do something like:

```
public interface Constants
{
    public char NUMBER_ONE = '1';
    public long A_LONG_TIME_AGO = 1321322;
    public String CANT_BREAK_WITH_IRON_PICKAXE= "OBSIDIAN";
}
```

There are many advantages in using interfaces: they don't need to be instantiated, won't slow down your system with IO access, and all attributes are static final.

---

However, if you need to load the values during runtime, then use properties files. Although all answers here are good, the only one I consider good enough is Spring's @Configuration and @ImportResource, which are injected, allow for nice mocking, and integrate nicely with the rest of the Spring framework, and can be easily overridden with -D from the command line.

Example on how to load properties files using a mix of xml and properties files: [Spring-Boot: How do I reference application.properties in an @ImportResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21470409/spring-boot-how-do-i-reference-application-properties-in-an-importresource)